# How to sleep and wake google coral development board for a given time

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, google-coral, edge-tpu

I'm new to stack overflow I needed help with my project on the Google coral dev board. I wanted to know how to make the board sleep for given time then run an operation and wake up. I really am stuck on this hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance
tejasawasarmol@gmail.com
Macquarie university

Answer (score 0):

You can see the section named : 'Entering Suspend' in https://github.com/mbrooksx/draft-coral-appnotes/blob/main/PowerSavings.pdf for sleeping and waking up the dev board.